# How to generate custom PDF documents with text and images from user input Android

Tags: java, android, pdf-generation, user-input, document

In my project I want users to be able to create custom documents with text and images with the document then being saved to PDF format.

I would like that document to be generated as blank at first and then the user can insert text boxes and images from a gallery, both of which can be moved, resized, or deleted. I would also like a function to add new pages, with undo and redo last action buttons.

Is this possible in Android Studio? I've watched some tutorials and they use EditText for text input but these are not user-generated, or moveable. Same goes for image insertion.

Does anybody have any documentation on creating custom documents of this nature? I am coding in Java.

Thanks.

Comment: You can explore iText.

Comment: @Hades I was looking at iText, seems to be a good solution for creating documents. Do you think if I implemented user-generated dynamic EditTexts and Images this would work?

Comment: You can take a look to JasperReports. Its easy to use